# Getting AnalysisException on dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset

I am trying to read CSV file in scala using dataset. And after that I am performing some operation. But my code is throwing error.
Below is my code:

```
 final case class AadharData(date:String,
                                    registrar:String,
                                    agency:String,
                                    state:String,
                                    district:String,
                                    subDistrict:String,
                                    pinCode:Int,
                                    gender:String,
                                    age:Int,
                                    aadharGenerated:Int,
                                    rejected:Int,
                                    mobileNo:Double,
                                    email:String)

     val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("GDP").master("local").getOrCreate()
     import spark.implicits._
     val a = spark.read.option("header", false).csv("D:\\BGH\\Spark\\aadhaar_data.csv").as[AadharData]
     val b = a.map(rec=>{
          (rec.registrar,1)
        }).groupByKey(f=>f._1).collect()
```

And I am getting below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`date`' given input columns: [_c0, _c2, _c1, _c3, _c5, _c8, _c9, _c7, _c6, _c11, _c12, _c10, _c4];
```

Any help is appreciated:
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`date`' given input columns: [_c0, _c2, _c1, _c3, _c5, _c8, _c9, _c7, _c6, _c11, _c12, _c10, _c4];

The above *error is because you have used header option as false* (`.option("header", false)`) so *spark generates column names as _c0, _c1 and so on..* But *while typecasting the generated dataframe using a case class you used column names different than the ones already generated*. **Thus the above error happened**.

**Solution**

You should *tell spark sql to generate the names used in the case class* and also *tell it to inferschema too* as

```
val columnNames = classOf[AadharData].getDeclaredFields.map(x => x.getName)
val a = sqlContext.read.option("header", false).option("inferSchema", true)
  .csv("D:\\BGH\\Spark\\aadhaar_data.csv").toDF(columnNames:_*).as[AadharData]
```

The above error should go away

Comment: There are some int fields in case class and it is giving error because the object is looking for String type parameter

Comment: which object  is looking for String type?

Comment: a is expecting string for all columns

Comment: for example pinCode is a int in case class and it is giving error 'Cannot up cast `pinCode` from string to int as it may truncate'

Comment: I too had the same issue and inferSchema option solved it for me